# How to keep SFTP connection alive with PHPStorm?

Tags: phpstorm, sftp

I use PHPStorm to upload my files into my development server (using SFTP), every time I save.

The problem is PHPStorm do log-in to the server, before every attempt to upload (after every save), which causes a delay of about 5 seconds.

This is really annoying and time consuming, when you (save) upload files at least 4 times in a minute.

Is there anyway to keep PHPStorm connected to my server, so it just takes time to upload files (instead of logging in every single time).

I want to it to login once and keep uploading every time I press save.

Comment: Nope, unfortunately: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-674

Answer (score 3):

After trying many things and reading all the comments from the [link](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-674#) sent by @LazyOne I found it possible with this simple trick:

```
Tools -> Deployment -> Browse Remote Host
```

Just keep this tab away, no need to use it. It will keep the connection alive, but it still disconnect from time to time. (still better than nothing).

Comment: The latest version 9 doesn't keep connection alive with this trick

Comment: Yes I'm not sure about that as I am using 8.* but even as I said still not that best solution for me (I keep the tab away I don't close minimise it completely, trying to tell the IDE I am still looking here so don't disconnect).

Comment: Thank you for this, this actually did the thing for me in Phpstorm 10.0.3.